# Stop Linux from allocating more memory to a process

Tags: linux, busybox, out-of-memory

I want to test that a process properly kills itself and restarts when it can't allocate needed memory. One idea I had was to start other memory-consuming processes and hope that OOM killer kills the process being tested, but:

1) this isn't quite the same;

2) it may kill other processes instead;

3) since this is an embedded system, I don't have any programs available except for the system under test and BusyBox.

Is there a more direct way to ensure that Linux won't allocate memory to a process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ulimit -v amount_of_memory
./binary
```